# Strange NMAP output

Tags: networking, linux-networking, port, nmap

I am trying to scan TCP port 8092 of a host using `nmap 7.60`. When I execute nmap without root privileges it says that the port is filtered, but if I try to scan it with `sudo` it tells me that the port is actually open. Also without root privileges `nmap` is telling me that the host is down, but it is actually replying to ICMP requests.

**Host is down:**

```
$ nmap -vv -n -p 8092 10.88.153.90

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-03-06 11:59 CET
Initiating Ping Scan at 11:59
Scanning 10.88.153.90 [2 ports]
Completed Ping Scan at 11:59, 3.00s elapsed (1 total hosts)
Nmap scan report for 10.88.153.90 [host down, received no-response]
Read data files from: /usr/bin/../share/nmap
Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -Pn
Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 3.04 seconds
```

**Host is up, but TCP port 8092 is blocked:**

```
$ nmap -vv -n -p 8092 10.88.153.90 -Pn

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-03-06 12:00 CET
Initiating Connect Scan at 12:00
Scanning 10.88.153.90 [1 port]
Completed Connect Scan at 12:00, 2.00s elapsed (1 total ports)
Nmap scan report for 10.88.153.90
Host is up, received user-set.
Scanned at 2019-03-06 12:00:04 CET for 2s

PORT     STATE    SERVICE REASON
8092/tcp filtered unknown no-response

Read data files from: /usr/bin/../share/nmap
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 2.04 seconds
```

**With sudo: Host is up and Port 8092 is open:**

(which isn't completely true, because I am unable to retrieve any files over this port.)

```
$ sudo nmap -vv -n -p 8092 10.88.153.90

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-03-06 12:00 CET
Initiating Ping Scan at 12:00
Scanning 10.88.153.90 [4 ports]
Completed Ping Scan at 12:00, 0.22s elapsed (1 total hosts)
Initiating SYN Stealth Scan at 12:00
Scanning 10.88.153.90 [1 port]
Discovered open port 8092/tcp on 10.88.153.90
Completed SYN Stealth Scan at 12:00, 0.23s elapsed (1 total ports)
Nmap scan report for 10.88.153.90
Host is up, received echo-reply ttl 64 (0.00025s latency).
Scanned at 2019-03-06 12:00:13 CET for 1s

PORT     STATE SERVICE REASON
8092/tcp open  unknown syn-ack ttl 64

Read data files from: /usr/bin/../share/nmap
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.62 seconds
           Raw packets sent: 6 (240B) | Rcvd: 13 (516B)
```

**At the same time, I have a stable ping to this host:**

```
$ ping 10.88.153.90 -c 4
PING 10.88.153.90 (10.88.153.90) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.88.153.90: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.242 ms
64 bytes from 10.88.153.90: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.162 ms
64 bytes from 10.88.153.90: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.169 ms
64 bytes from 10.88.153.90: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.152 ms

--- 10.88.153.90 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 77ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.152/0.181/0.242/0.036 ms
```

Both the server from where I am executing those commands and the `10.88.153.90` are behind a firewall but they should be able to see each other and all the ports beeing exposed, but apparently, this isn't the case. 
This is from within 10.88.153.90:

```
$ netstat -tulnp | grep 8092
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8092            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      194735/nginx: maste
```

I have exactly the same situation with port 22 and I am able to connect to 10.88.153.90 using another private IP from a different network configured to another port of the device, but when I try to connect to 10.88.153.90 I got connection timeout:

```
$ ssh -vvv root@10.88.153.90
OpenSSH_7.7p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/ubuntu/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 10.88.153.90 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 10.88.153.90 [10.88.153.90] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 10.88.153.90 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 10.88.153.90 port 22: Connection timed out
```

**My question is:** Why does the host/port appear to be up/open, but I still can't connect to it?

Answer (score 0):

At the end, it appeared that I have two default gateways configured on this device and I needed to remove the second one and add routing to the specific network from where my request originates.